# Debug Assertion Failed in Visual Studio c

Tags: c, debugging

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

 FILE *pfd;//will get the file we are gone read from
 char fileName[40];//get files name
 char line[1024];
 FILE *simulate;//will get the file we are gone read from
 char line2[1024];
 int arrSize=argc-2;
 station * stations=( station * )malloc(sizeof(station)*(arrSize));//intilzing ther array 

 int i=2;//Auxiliary variable for the first for loop-reads information from all fiels
 int j=0; //Auxiliary variable to help as clean the memory
 ClientsLinkedList* data;
 Link * temp;//temp varbale to help us clean the memory
 Link * tempNext;



 if(stations==NULL)
 {
  printf("Failed to allocate memory");
 }

 for(i;i<argc;i++)

 {
  data=CreateClientsLinkedList();
  stations[i].m_clients=*data;

  strcpy(fileName,argv[i]);
  ///* Open the file.  If NULL is returned there was an error */

   if((pfd = fopen("station.txt" , "r")) == NULL) 
    {
     printf("Error Opening File.\n");


     }

    while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), pfd) != NULL ) 
    {
   ReadByCharName(line,stations,i);
    }

    fclose(pfd);  /* Close the file */
  }

 ////************************************************reading from simulation file*******************************************

 /*** Open the file.  If NULL is returned there was an error */
  if((simulate = fopen("simulation.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
  {
    printf("Error Opening File.\n");

  }

  while( fgets(line, sizeof(line2), simulate) != NULL ) 
  {
     ReadSimulation( line2,arrSize,stations);
  }

  fclose(simulate);  /* Close the file */


 ////*********************************************clening memory****************************************

 for(j;j<arrSize;j++)
  {
   temp=stations[j].m_clients.m_head;
   while(temp!=NULL)
   {
    tempNext=temp->m_next;
    free(temp);
    temp=tempNext;

   }


  }
    free(stations);
  return 0;

}
```

this is the main of our program that shold get one simoulation file and unknow number of station files and initilizing the data structure from them. 
but when we try to run the project we get a "Debug Assertion Failed" error.
please if you can help us to solve the priblem we need to submit the project by sunday.

thank you!

Comment: Please stop writing code. If you're asking for help on a simple homework question, and your intro class is using C, you're bound for failure.

Comment: @Conrad: My intro class used C. It was great. At my school engineering majors had to take C. CS is the only one using java.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least a bug here: `stations[i].m_clients=*data;`: i starts at 2, I believe.